# React-Bootstrap / Panel / Font Awesome - How do I have a font awesome icon in the header of a panel

Tags: font-awesome, react-bootstrap

For a panel, I wanted to have a font awesome icon in the header with some title. How do I do that?

Want to use:

```
<Panel header = "Panel Title" bsStyle="primary">
</Panel>
```

But I need something like this:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
     <i class="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></i> Panel Title
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i recall you can add an Element in the header attribute

```
<Panel header={<div><span className="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></span> <span>Header</span></div>}>Content</Panel>
```

or

```
const title = (
  <div>
     <span className="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></span>
     <span>Header</span>
  </div>
);

<Panel header={title}>Content</Panel>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Billing
For some reason the above code was putting the icon and header text in different lines. I will debug more later but at the moment, following worked.

{<div><span className="fa fa-list-alt fa-fw"></span> <span>Header</span></div>}